# Priority-based queueing in AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm new in **AnyLogic** and I'm developing a model for a real Emergency Department. I have developed almost everything I need, however I'm having trouble with **priority queueing**. In our model we have 2 different priorities for patients (red and yellow), where red has a higher priority in queueing. For example, if a yellow-priority patient and a red-priority patient are both in queue for going to the X-ray, the red should be picked first (Priority-based queueing NOT LIFO).

I saw a lot of posts that explained how to do this but none of them worked for me. I tried making a *parameter* called "priority" within the "Patient" agent and using "agent.priority=1;" for assigning priorities on the exit of a *SelectOutput* and then selecting the "Priority-based" option in the *Queue* but that doesn't seem to work as I get the following error:

[Queue priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT8wu.png)

[Output priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvmmR.png)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkOkj.png)

I also tried typing "patient.priority=2;" instead of "agent.priority=2;", also using a variable instead of a parameter, and also initializing the variable's value with the following formula: uniform() < 0.7 = 1 : 3. But this didn't worked.

Does anyone know how to use priority-based queueing or some sort of walkaround I could use? It's for my final project for becoming an engineer!

The version I'm using is AnyLogic Professional 7.0.2

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old AnyLogic version that still applies the old process-modelling library where entities are NOT actual agents. Instead of `agent` you could try `entity`.

In the fields causing the errors (where you typed `agent`), is there a small "lightbulb" when you have the cursor in the field? If so, what keywords does it allow you to write? Please see [this article](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling) to understand what I am talking about

Strongly suggest you upgrade asap :)

Comment: Thank you very much Benjamin! I thought the lightbulb was just a warning but It helped us to solve the problem, thank you for taking your time to answer this question and the incredible article provided! We spent several days looking for the solution but it was right in front of us :)

We will take your advice and upgrade it and, for other people with the same issue, if the lightbulb does not show any commands if you are on hover with the mouse, use Ctrl+Enter and it may show these commands.

Comment: @IgnacioAristimuño Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)